# Compiling g-wrap

Tags: gnome, guile

I am trying to compile G-Wrap from http://www.nongnu.org/g-wrap/download.html.

When I go through the usual steps (configure, make, make install) however, I get some errors in the `make` step:

## Step 1: `./configure`

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... no
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking size of long... 8
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for long long int... yes
checking for unsigned long long int... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for EOVERFLOW... yes
checking for vasnprintf... no
checking for long double... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking for wint_t... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for alloca as a compiler built-in... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for SIZE_MAX... yes
checking absolute name of <stdint.h>... ///usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h
checking whether stdint.h conforms to C99... yes
checking absolute name of <stdio.h>... ///usr/include/stdio.h
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for wcslen... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking whether <wchar.h> is standalone... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for alloca as a compiler built-in... (cached) yes
checking for vasprintf... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBFFI... yes
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of ssize_t... 8
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: checking for guile 2.2
configure: found guile 2.2
checking for guile... /usr/local/bin/guile
checking for Guile version >= 2.2... 2.2.3
checking for guild... /usr/local/bin/guild
checking for guile-config... /usr/local/bin/guile-config
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for GUILE... yes
checking for guile-2.2... no
configure: Using /usr/local/bin/guile
checking for GLIB... yes
configure: building GLib 2.0 support
checking whether gcc accepts -std=gnu99... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: creating g-wrap/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating guile/Makefile
config.status: creating guile/g-wrap-2.0-guile.pc
config.status: creating guile/g-wrap/Makefile
config.status: creating guile/g-wrap/gw/Makefile
config.status: creating guile/test/Makefile
config.status: creating guile/run-guile
config.status: creating guile/examples/Makefile
config.status: creating scheme48/Makefile
config.status: creating scheme48/g-wrap/Makefile
config.status: creating scheme48/g-wrap/gw/Makefile
config.status: creating scheme48/test/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating g-wrap-config
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: creating g-wrap/ffi-support.h
config.status: g-wrap/ffi-support.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing run-guile-exec commands
```

## Step 2: `make`

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/lib'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/lib'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/lib'
Making all in g-wrap
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/g-wrap'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/g-wrap'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/g-wrap'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/g-wrap'
Making all in test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/test'
Making all in guile
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile'
Making all in g-wrap
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile/g-wrap'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile/g-wrap'
  CC       guile-runtime.lo
guile-runtime.c: In function 'gw_guile_add_subr_method':
guile-runtime.c:182:9: error: 'scm_class_top' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
         specializers = scm_cons (scm_class_top, specializers);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:168:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_top;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c:189:5: error: 'scm_class_top' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
     specializers = scm_append_x (scm_list_2 (specializers, scm_class_top));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:168:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_top;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c:225:23: error: 'scm_class_method' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
                       scm_list_5 (scm_class_method,
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:180:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_method;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c: In function 'allocate_generic_variable':
guile-runtime.c:355:28: error: 'scm_class_generic' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
                            scm_list_3 (scm_class_generic, k_name, sym));
                            ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:174:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_generic;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c:357:3: error: 'scm_class_generic' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
   } else if (scm_is_true (scm_call_2 (is_a_p_proc, scm_variable_ref (var),
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:174:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_generic;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c:357:3: error: 'scm_class_generic' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
   } else if (scm_is_true (scm_call_2 (is_a_p_proc, scm_variable_ref (var),
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:174:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_generic;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c:367:28: error: 'scm_class_generic' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
                            scm_list_5 (scm_class_generic,
                            ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:174:20: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED SCM scm_class_generic;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
guile-runtime.c: In function 'gw_guile_handle_wrapper_error':
guile-runtime.c:759:7: error: 'scm_memory_error' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
       scm_memory_error(func_name);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile.h:128:0,
                 from ../../guile/g-wrap/guile-compatibility.h:25,
                 from guile-runtime.c:32:
/usr/local/include/guile/2.2/libguile/deprecated.h:148:21: note: declared here
 SCM_DEPRECATED void scm_memory_error (const char *subr) SCM_NORETURN;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:592: recipe for target 'guile-runtime.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [guile-runtime.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile/g-wrap'
Makefile:656: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile/g-wrap'
Makefile:518: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15/guile'
Makefile:673: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/GuileScheme/g-wrap-1.9.15'
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It says: `cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`. That makes warnings about deprecations pop up as errors, which then cancel the compilation process.

How can I fix the use of deprecated code or alternatively: Can I somehow savely ignore these and continue compiling despite usage of deprecated code?

## System Info

- Ubuntu 17.04
- G-Wrap version: `1.9.15`
- GCC version: `gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0`
- Guile version: `2.2.3`

Comment: `guile` version is missing in your "info".

Comment: @KnudLarsen added : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to compile G-Wrap .... g-wrap-1.9.15.tar.gz

"g-wrap-1.9.15" : `sudo apt install g-wrap`

If you really want to build it, install the default guile-2.0.13: `sudo apt install guile-2.0-dev` ... I.e. g-wrap is too old (2016) to use guile-2.2 .

```
cd g-wrap-1.9.15/ 
./configure 
make                // no errors
```

Comment: I tried to use the apt way before, however, Guile would state that it has no code for module g-wrap, when trying to compile guile-gnome (that is the further goal I had). So I thought "maybe it will be put in the right place, when I compile g-wrap myself". Thanks for the hint about g-wrap being too old.  I guess there is nothing I can do when using guile-2.2.3.